# Why MongoDB is so slow on some queries while using IXSCAN as a winning plan?

Tags: index, performance, mongodb, query-performance

I have DB with about 30M records in a collection with about 100GB collection size (total documents and indexes).

I have a compound index that filters data based on user_id and some other fields like: `is_active`, `is_logged_in`, etc.

With `MongoDB Compass` I see slow queries of about 10s, 20s or even 40 seconds! I ran the exact same query and result is fetched less than 500ms (though it may get cached on second try).

When I get that ongoing `op` stat, I see the following lock status:

```
 "lockStats": {
         "Global": {
             "acquireCount": {
                 "r": 574
             }
         },
         "MMAPV1Journal": {
             "acquireCount": {
                 "r": 295
             },
             "acquireWaitCount": {
                 "r": 2
             },
             "timeAcquiringMicros": {
                 "r": 15494
             }
         },
 }
```

`acquireCount`: Number of times the operation acquired the lock in the specified mode is so high compared to the fast query (on another collection) that has the below status:

```
"lockStats": {
         "Global": {
             "acquireCount": {
                 "r": 2
             }
         },
         "MMAPV1Journal": {
             "acquireCount": {
                 "r": 1
             }
         },
         "Database": {
             "acquireCount": {
                 "r": 1
             }
         },
         "Collection": {
             "acquireCount": {
                 "R": 1
             }
         }
     }
```

When operations are slow, and a user that has many records take so long it has domino effect on all the other operations after a few seconds.

When I explain the query on the large collection I can see the result that it has used an index:

```
{
    "queryPlanner" : {
        "plannerVersion" : 1,
        "namespace" : "cuda.call_history",
        "indexFilterSet" : false,
        "parsedQuery" : {
            "$and" : [ 
                {
                    "$or" : [ 
                        {
                            "trk.0.extra_data.spam.is_spam" : {
                                "$eq" : false
                            }
                        }, 
                        {
                            "$nor" : [ 
                                {
                                    "trk.0.extra_data.spam.is_spam" : {
                                        "$exists" : true
                                    }
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }, 
                {
                    "is_removed" : {
                        "$eq" : false
                    }
                }, 
                {
                    "user_id" : {
                        "$eq" : "00000000000040008000000000002a5d"
                    }
                }, 
                {
                    "trk.0.direction" : {
                        "$eq" : "ingress"
                    }
                }, 
                {
                    "trk.0.type" : {
                        "$eq" : "fax"
                    }
                }, 
                {
                    "date" : {
                        "$lt" : "2018-01-09 10:36:31"
                    }
                }, 
                {
                    "date" : {
                        "$gt" : "1970-01-01 00:00:00"
                    }
                }, 
                {
                    "trk.0.data.status" : {
                        "$in" : [ 
                            "p_received", 
                            "success"
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        "winningPlan" : {
            "stage" : "FETCH",
            "filter" : {
                "$and" : [ 
                    {
                        "$or" : [ 
                            {
                                "trk.0.extra_data.spam.is_spam" : {
                                    "$eq" : false
                                }
                            }, 
                            {
                                "$nor" : [ 
                                    {
                                        "trk.0.extra_data.spam.is_spam" : {
                                            "$exists" : true
                                        }
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    }, 
                    {
                        "trk.0.type" : {
                            "$eq" : "fax"
                        }
                    }, 
                    {
                        "date" : {
                            "$lt" : "2018-01-09 10:36:31"
                        }
                    }, 
                    {
                        "date" : {
                            "$gt" : "1970-01-01 00:00:00"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
            "inputStage" : {
                "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                "keyPattern" : {
                    "user_id" : 1,
                    "trk.0.direction" : 1,
                    "is_read" : 1,
                    "trk.0.data.status" : 1,
                    "is_removed" : 1
                },
                "indexName" : "user_id_direction_is_read_status_is_removed",
                "isMultiKey" : false,
                "isUnique" : false,
                "isSparse" : false,
                "isPartial" : false,
                "indexVersion" : 1,
                "direction" : "forward",
                "indexBounds" : {
                    "user_id" : [ 
                        "[\"00000000000040008000000000002a5d\", \"00000000000040008000000000002a5d\"]"
                    ],
                    "trk.0.direction" : [ 
                        "[\"ingress\", \"ingress\"]"
                    ],
                    "is_read" : [ 
                        "[MinKey, MaxKey]"
                    ],
                    "trk.0.data.status" : [ 
                        "[\"p_received\", \"p_received\"]", 
                        "[\"success\", \"success\"]"
                    ],
                    "is_removed" : [ 
                        "[false, false]"
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        "rejectedPlans" : [ 
            {
                "stage" : "FETCH",
                "filter" : {
                    "$and" : [ 
                        {
                            "$or" : [ 
                                {
                                    "trk.0.extra_data.spam.is_spam" : {
                                        "$eq" : false
                                    }
                                }, 
                                {
                                    "$nor" : [ 
                                        {
                                            "trk.0.extra_data.spam.is_spam" : {
                                                "$exists" : true
                                            }
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]
                        }, 
                        {
                            "is_removed" : {
                                "$eq" : false
                            }
                        }, 
                        {
                            "trk.0.direction" : {
                                "$eq" : "ingress"
                            }
                        }, 
                        {
                            "trk.0.type" : {
                                "$eq" : "fax"
                            }
                        }, 
                        {
                            "trk.0.data.status" : {
                                "$in" : [ 
                                    "p_received", 
                                    "success"
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "inputStage" : {
                    "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                    "keyPattern" : {
                        "user_id" : 1,
                        "date" : -1
                    },
                    "indexName" : "user_id_date",
                    "isMultiKey" : false,
                    "isUnique" : false,
                    "isSparse" : false,
                    "isPartial" : false,
                    "indexVersion" : 1,
                    "direction" : "forward",
                    "indexBounds" : {
                        "user_id" : [ 
                            "[\"00000000000040008000000000002a5d\", \"00000000000040008000000000002a5d\"]"
                        ],
                        "date" : [ 
                            "(\"2018-01-09 10:36:31\", \"1970-01-01 00:00:00\")"
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }, 
            {
                "stage" : "FETCH",
                "filter" : {
                    "$and" : [ 
                        {
                            "$or" : [ 
                                {
                                    "trk.0.extra_data.spam.is_spam" : {
                                        "$eq" : false
                                    }
                                }, 
                                {
                                    "$nor" : [ 
                                        {
                                            "trk.0.extra_data.spam.is_spam" : {
                                                "$exists" : true
                                            }
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]
                        }, 
                        {
                            "is_removed" : {
                                "$eq" : false
                            }
                        }, 
                        {
                            "trk.0.direction" : {
                                "$eq" : "ingress"
                            }
                        }, 
                        {
                            "trk.0.type" : {
                                "$eq" : "fax"
                            }
                        }, 
                        {
                            "date" : {
                                "$lt" : "2018-01-09 10:36:31"
                            }
                        }, 
                        {
                            "date" : {
                                "$gt" : "1970-01-01 00:00:00"
                            }
                        }, 
                        {
                            "trk.0.data.status" : {
                                "$in" : [ 
                                    "p_received", 
                                    "success"
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "inputStage" : {
                    "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                    "keyPattern" : {
                        "user_id" : 1,
                        "to" : 1,
                        "from" : 1
                    },
                    "indexName" : "user_id_to_from",
                    "isMultiKey" : false,
                    "isUnique" : false,
                    "isSparse" : false,
                    "isPartial" : false,
                    "indexVersion" : 1,
                    "direction" : "forward",
                    "indexBounds" : {
                        "user_id" : [ 
                            "[\"00000000000040008000000000002a5d\", \"00000000000040008000000000002a5d\"]"
                        ],
                        "to" : [ 
                            "[MinKey, MaxKey]"
                        ],
                        "from" : [ 
                            "[MinKey, MaxKey]"
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    "executionStats" : {
        "executionSuccess" : true,
        "nReturned" : 4682,
        "executionTimeMillis" : 2072,
        "totalKeysExamined" : 4688,
        "totalDocsExamined" : 4682,
        "executionStages" : {
            "stage" : "FETCH",
            "filter" : {
                "$and" : [ 
                    {
                        "$or" : [ 
                            {
                                "trk.0.extra_data.spam.is_spam" : {
                                    "$eq" : false
                                }
                            }, 
                            {
                                "$nor" : [ 
                                    {
                                        "trk.0.extra_data.spam.is_spam" : {
                                            "$exists" : true
                                        }
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    }, 
                    {
                        "trk.0.type" : {
                            "$eq" : "fax"
                        }
                    }, 
                    {
                        "date" : {
                            "$lt" : "2018-01-09 10:36:31"
                        }
                    }, 
                    {
                        "date" : {
                            "$gt" : "1970-01-01 00:00:00"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
            "nReturned" : 4682,
            "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 710,
            "works" : 4897,
            "advanced" : 4682,
            "needTime" : 5,
            "needYield" : 209,
            "saveState" : 234,
            "restoreState" : 234,
            "isEOF" : 1,
            "invalidates" : 1,
            "docsExamined" : 4682,
            "alreadyHasObj" : 0,
            "inputStage" : {
                "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                "nReturned" : 4682,
                "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 305,
                "works" : 4688,
                "advanced" : 4682,
                "needTime" : 5,
                "needYield" : 0,
                "saveState" : 234,
                "restoreState" : 234,
                "isEOF" : 1,
                "invalidates" : 1,
                "keyPattern" : {
                    "user_id" : 1,
                    "trk.0.direction" : 1,
                    "is_read" : 1,
                    "trk.0.data.status" : 1,
                    "is_removed" : 1
                },
                "indexName" : "user_id_direction_is_read_status_is_removed",
                "isMultiKey" : false,
                "isUnique" : false,
                "isSparse" : false,
                "isPartial" : false,
                "indexVersion" : 1,
                "direction" : "forward",
                "indexBounds" : {
                    "user_id" : [ 
                        "[\"00000000000040008000000000002a5d\", \"00000000000040008000000000002a5d\"]"
                    ],
                    "trk.0.direction" : [ 
                        "[\"ingress\", \"ingress\"]"
                    ],
                    "is_read" : [ 
                        "[MinKey, MaxKey]"
                    ],
                    "trk.0.data.status" : [ 
                        "[\"p_received\", \"p_received\"]", 
                        "[\"success\", \"success\"]"
                    ],
                    "is_removed" : [ 
                        "[false, false]"
                    ]
                },
                "keysExamined" : 4688,
                "seeks" : 6,
                "dupsTested" : 0,
                "dupsDropped" : 0,
                "seenInvalidated" : 0
            }
        }
    },
    "serverInfo" : {
        "host" : “hs1.mydomain.com”,
        "port" : 27017,
        "version" : "3.4.10",
        "gitVersion" : "078f28920cb24de0dd479b5ea6c66c644f6326e9"
    },
    "ok" : 1.0
}
```

`keysExamined` is just 4,688! It is not much compared to the total data of the collection which is 30M documents. When Mongo gets slow when it has domino effect, CPU usage and Memory is not high. Mongo just uses 40% of the memory. Disk partition is `Ext4` if that helps.

Another example of a very slow query in full details:

```
{
    "desc": "conn199276",
    "threadId": "140070259820288",
    "connectionId": 199276,
    "client": "client_server_ip:45590",
    "active": "true",
    "opid": 63869351,
    "secs_running": 36,
    "microsecs_running": 36136211,
    "op": "query",
    "ns": "cuda.call_history",
    "query": {
        "find": "call_history",
        "filter": {
            "is_removed": false,
            "trk.0.extra_data.spam.is_spam": true,
            "trk.0.direction": "ingress",
            "date": {
                "$gt": "1970-01-01 00:00:00",
                "$lt": "4001-01-01 00:00:00"
            },
            "trk.0.extra_data.status": {
                "$in": [
                    "success",
                    "p_received"
                ]
            },
            "trk.0.type": "clk",
            "owner_id": "00000000000040008000000000003828"
        },
        "sort": {
            "date": -1
        },
        "limit": 31
    },
    "numYields": 6600,
    "locks": {},
    "waitingForLock": "false",
    "lockStats": {
        "Global": {
            "acquireCount": {
                "r": 13200
            }
        },
        "MMAPV1Journal": {
            "acquireCount": {
                "r": 6611
            },
            "acquireWaitCount": {
                "r": 9
            },
            "timeAcquiringMicros": {
                "r": 50854
            }
        },
        "Database": {
            "acquireCount": {
                "r": 6600
            }
        },
        "Collection": {
            "acquireCount": {
                "R": 6600
            },
            "acquireWaitCount": {
                "R": 11
            },
            "timeAcquiringMicros": {
                "R": 163707
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Output of `db.stats()`:

```
rs0:PRIMARY> db.stats()
{
    "db" : "cuda",
    "collections" : 5,
    "views" : 0,
    "objects" : 55009248,
    "avgObjSize" : 2018.6135346551184,
    "dataSize" : 111042412544,
    "storageSize" : 113055362336,
    "numExtents" : 100,
    "indexes" : 7,
    "indexSize" : 14223460160,
    "fileSize" : 133012914176,
    "nsSizeMB" : 16,
    "extentFreeList" : {
        "num" : 0,
        "totalSize" : 0
    },
    "dataFileVersion" : {
        "major" : 4,
        "minor" : 22
    },
    "ok" : 1
}
```

`mongostat` displays the below result, I think fault number is high:

```
insert query update delete getmore command flushes mapped vsize   res faults qrw arw net_in net_out conn set repl                time
     5    93      4     *0       0    64|0       0         282G 9.11G     26 0|0 0|0  64.3k    187k  481 rs0  PRI Jan 10 06:25:14.476
    *0   107     *0      1       0    58|0       0         282G 9.14G      4 0|0 0|0  51.5k    247k  481 rs0  PRI Jan 10 06:25:15.475
     2    88      5     *0       0    70|0       0         282G 9.04G     26 0|0 0|0  61.5k    245k  481 rs0  PRI Jan 10 06:25:16.476
     3    98      2     *0       0    71|0       0         282G 9.12G      6 0|0 0|0  59.6k    274k  481 rs0  PRI Jan 10 06:25:17.474
     1   105     *0      1       0    82|0       0         282G 9.10G     14 0|0 0|0  63.4k    254k  481 rs0  PRI Jan 10 06:25:18.476
     1    88      2     *0       0    68|0       0         282G 9.12G     75 0|0 0|0  49.9k    194k  481 rs0  PRI Jan 10 06:25:19.476
     5   120      4     *0       0    78|0       0         282G 9.11G      5 0|0 0|0  75.7k    548k  484 rs0  PRI Jan 10 06:25:20.476
     3    89     *0      4       0    64|0       0         282G 9.14G     19 0|0 0|0  55.3k   1.59m  483 rs0  PRI Jan 10 06:25:21.476
    *0    81     *0     *0       0    62|0       0         282G 9.17G      0 0|0 0|0  46.9k    265k  481 rs0  PRI Jan 10 06:25:22.476
     6   105      3     *0       0    67|0       0         282G 9.15G     49 0|0 0|0  61.8k    240k  481 rs0  PRI Jan 10 06:25:23.475
```

**And under load we have high page faults:**

```
insert query update delete getmore command flushes mapped vsize   res faults  qrw  arw net_in net_out conn set repl                time
     1    96     *0     *0       0    70|0       0         282G 10.9G    597  0|0  2|0  59.1k   1.06m  484 rs0  PRI Jan 10 07:48:45.061
     1   103      3     *0       0    79|0       0         282G 10.9G    715  0|0  0|0  66.4k    176k  484 rs0  PRI Jan 10 07:48:46.060
     2   102     *0     *0       0    72|0       0         282G 10.9G    718  0|0  2|0  59.6k    154k  484 rs0  PRI Jan 10 07:48:47.060
     2   104      2      1       0    83|0       0         282G 11.0G    692  0|0  3|0  68.7k    154k  483 rs0  PRI Jan 10 07:48:48.061
     2   103      2     *0       0    86|0       0         282G 11.0G    743  0|0  1|0  64.2k    154k  482 rs0  PRI Jan 10 07:48:49.059
    *0   116      2     *0       0    95|0       0         282G 11.0G    715  0|0  2|0  68.5k    237k  484 rs0  PRI Jan 10 07:48:50.060
     1   112      6      1       0    78|0       0         282G 11.0G    595  0|0  2|0  74.3k    231k  481 rs0  PRI Jan 10 07:48:51.061
     2   137      5      1       0    83|0       0         282G 11.0G    733  0|0  3|0  81.6k    301k  480 rs0  PRI Jan 10 07:48:52.060
     3   157      5      1       0    92|0       0         282G 11.0G    697  0|0  3|0  89.5k    183k  481 rs0  PRI Jan 10 07:48:53.059
     4   102      3     *0       0    73|0       0         282G 10.9G    599  0|0  1|0  67.1k    154k  480 rs0  PRI Jan 10 07:48:54.060
```

We have about 15GB of free memory that `MongoDB` does not use!

On peak we reach 400 OPS, and 500 connections per seconds. Is there anything I could do to **improve the performance?**

---

**EDIT**

`iostat` output of disk:

```
Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s    rkB/s    wkB/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await r_await w_await  svctm  %util
sda               0.00    87.00    7.00  392.00   460.00  2544.00    15.06     0.08    0.22    8.00    0.08   0.12   4.80
dm-0              0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
dm-1              0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
dm-2              0.00     0.00    7.00  478.00   460.00  2536.00    12.35     0.09    0.19    8.00    0.08   0.10   4.80

Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s    rkB/s    wkB/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await r_await w_await  svctm  %util
sda               0.00     0.00   84.00    6.00  3620.00    56.00    81.69     0.82    8.84    9.48    0.00   4.13  37.20
dm-0              0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
dm-1              0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
dm-2              0.00     0.00   85.00    6.00  3692.00    56.00    82.37     0.82    8.75    9.36    0.00   4.09  37.20

Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s    rkB/s    wkB/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await r_await w_await  svctm  %util
sda               0.00     0.00   57.00    3.00  2804.00    52.00    95.20     0.44    7.73    7.79    6.67   4.80  28.80
dm-0              0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
dm-1              0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
dm-2              0.00     0.00   56.00    3.00  2732.00    52.00    94.37     0.44    7.80    7.86    6.67   4.88  28.80
```

Another snapshot:

```
Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s    rkB/s    wkB/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await r_await w_await  svctm  %util
sda               0.00    11.00  267.67    5.00 20813.33    97.33   153.38     1.28    4.68    4.70    3.73   3.56  97.07
dm-0              0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
dm-1              0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
dm-2              0.00     0.00  267.67   16.00 20806.67    97.33   147.38     1.28    4.50    4.70    1.17   3.42  97.07

Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s    rkB/s    wkB/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await r_await w_await  svctm  %util
sda               0.00    21.00  221.67    3.00 19089.33   110.67   170.92     1.18    5.26    5.16   12.44   3.95  88.80
dm-0              0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
dm-1              0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
dm-2              0.00     0.00  221.33   24.00 19061.33   110.67   156.29     1.18    4.82    5.17    1.56   3.62  88.80
```

---

**EDIT 2:**

The output of `iostat 1` in order to remove extra information based on read and write:

https://pastebin.com/32WuRSPF

Another result which `tps` reached around 1000:

https://pastebin.com/mrQdKZZF

Comment: Looks like that everything slows down when mongod goes to the disk. How many IOPS your disks can handle? Especially read IOPS and latency.

Comment: @JJussi Please see the edit part of the question, I have added `iostat` output.

Comment: @JJussi thank you for your time, how can I see that latency? is r_await, what we're looking for?

Comment: ?_await is average wait time in ms. You could run iostat without x-parameter and watch tps value to see iops. http://www.thattommyhall.com/2011/02/18/iops-linux-iostat/ Strange thing with mongodb is that latency plays a big role and it is hard to measure especially random read latency. Also "how storage is build" plays big role. F.ex. LVM on top of RAID is fast. RAID on top of LVM is slow, at least when both are software base.

Comment: @JJussi the output of `iostat 1` I've posted in the `EDIT2` part is the part tat  mongo queries took around `13 Second` after a while and then got back to normal.

Comment: There is something "hinky" here. Normally mongod eats all the free memory or at least that amount what is the size of DB totally (data + indexes) and when all data is at the memory, there is not much disk activity after that. Here you say that mongod eats only 40% of memory and still you get huge disk activity peaking almost 2k IOPS what is probably maximum what your storage can perform. Of course you can test with `dd if=/dev/dm-2 of=/dev/null count=100M` command your maximum IOPS and transfer rate

Comment: @JJussi this is the total size of the collection inside of the DB: `59.8 GB + 16.1 GB`. (At the first of the question I said 100 GB, I have removed an old collection which was unused.)

Comment: @JJussi I will benchmark disk performance by `hdparm` and will post the result here. Thank you.

Comment: @JJussi I used hdparm and I got `1099.23 MB/sec` for buffered disk reads and `8879.00 MB/sec` for cached reads! With this benchmark is disk the bottleneck?? More data: https://pastebin.com/aJyqTK7m

Comment: No, disk is not bottle neck for direct reads. Have to raise my hands... However, that memory consumption is still little bit mystery. Mongod should use all free memory.

Comment: From your comment on another recent question it sounds like you haven't solved this performance issue yet. It looks like you are using MongoDB 3.4.10 with the MMAPv1 storage engine on Linux. Can you confirm the specific O/S version and if you are still using the same MongoDB version? How much total RAM do you have? Can you also add a link to a pastebin with output of `db.call_history.getIndexes()`? Are you seeing this query frequently logged as slow in your MongoDB logs or only when you explain via Compass? Lastly, what metric are you using to determine that `mongod` is only using 40% of RAM?

Comment: One more data point as suggested in the answer mentioning the MongoDB Production Notes (which are definitely worth reviewing, if you haven't already): can you confirm your current readahead settings for the block device with your MongoDB `dbPath` using `sudo blockdev --report`?

Answer (score 1):

High disk readahead could be the reason why physical memory is underutilized. If it's high, for random reads the system might be reading a lot of data MongoDB does not need, thus "polluting" the file system cache. That in return could result in extra page faults.

I suggest making sure your system complies with the Recommended Configuration as per [Production Notes](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.4/administration/production-notes/#recommended-configuration).

Comment: How can I set readahead in `MongoDB`? Is there a way to set this on `MongoDB MMAPV1`?

Comment: `RA` in my disk server is set to `256`, I checked it with `blockdev --report` command. Is that a high number? Should I lower the value for `RA` (readahead)?